# Use jQuery to get non-json object from amazon s3

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-s3, jsonp

I'm trying to use jQuery to grab a file from amazonS3, but I'm running into the dreaded Cross-domain access policy issues. The current solution is to basically have a passthru interface that reads the file using php's readfile method. I don't personally like this because it uses the sites data (if it's limited, or payed for), and I think it would be better to get it directly from the amazon S3 link.

I looked up the possible solutions, and they all said either use JSONP or CORS. I don't want to use CORS, because multiple people use the server install, and I don't want there to be even more that they have to set up.

I tried JSONP (Code bellow), but I'm getting a syntax error because I'm not reading json data. I'm reading either text/plain or application/octet-stream.

Here is the json code I was trying with: (Hopefully it's formatted correctly)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<non-json file url goes here>',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'content'
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.enabled === true) {
        alert("done");
    }
});
```

Is there any way besides CORS and the current method to do what I want to do?

EDIT 1/26/2014:
Seriously, please stop suggesting CORS. I know I can use CORS, I'm asking if there's any way besides CORS. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use CORS, all you have to do is get another header in the response for your page, which you should be able to do on a page-by-page basis, right?

Here are some suggested ways depending on what server language you are using:

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Because then whoever installs the program on their server using their own S3 data store will have to configure CORS manually, which I don't want them to have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm looking at this scenario incorrectly, "they" (the people installing/running your code) don't have to do CORS configuration on their server -- "you" do, on the bucket that's being accessed.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

CORS checks the site where the external data is going to be coming from... to see if it allows cross-origin requests from the domain of the web page that's trying to request the data... so it's the *bucket* that needs to be configured for CORS, not the web server.

Does that help?

Comment: I understand this, but they use their own S3 data and buckets. It's not just one bucket that I've created, they create their own S3 buckets for their particular case. Currently, that means that they have to configure s3 to a degree anyway, but I don't want them to have to configure CORS as well.